# Permissions and current login check

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I use windows authentication login to connect to sql instance.
My user "Domain\MyName" is a part of two user groups:
"Domain\Admins" and "Domain\SQL_Admins"
Both groups appear under:
Instance-Security-Logins at SSMS.
How can I check under which login am I connected to the SSMS?
SELECT SYSTEM_USER or SP_WHO2 shows my windows user:"Domain\MyName"
How SSMS decides which login to use if my windows login is a member of couple domain groups?

Comment: it will give you the the highest combined (bar DENY's): so union your GRANTs intersected with your DENYs

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, ssms can combine permissions of couple logins in my case and I'll get the "highest" permissions of them? So in that case there wouldn't be any function to show me my current login(from the ssms logins list).
Right? Could you please share any link to learn more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a query to find a permissions origin:

```
select * 
from sys.login_token lt
join sys.server_principals sp on sp.sid = lt.sid;
```